# Window7 troubleshooting .exe is not opening

Tags: windows-7, window

I opened .exe file in internet explorer by mistake after that i am not able to open any exe files, all files are open in internet explorer. The .exe association is corrupted. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: this needs to go on SuperUser

and, thats kindda funny!! not that you probably think so at the moment.

Comment: ask this here http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 4):

try this [Restore the .exe file association in Windows Vista, after incorrectly associating it with another application](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/165/1/Restore-the-exe-file-association-in-Windows-Vista-after-incorrectly-associating-it-with-another-application.html)

Comment: Good link but some more explanation about what it does would be good.

Comment: @Sim: You noted that 'the .exe association is corrupted' and the title of the linked article is 'Restore the .exe file association in Windows Vista...' - it also applies to win 7

Comment: +1 for a good link -1 for not bothering to tell what the link points to. (I added a link description)

Comment: This does not always work. I'm seeing a case where creating a new user profile does not solve the problem although it should as we are fixing HKEY_CURRENT_USER. I'm going a little crazy right now. Microsoft offers this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950505#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways which is more extensive but also not helping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete this key in the registry (with `regedit.exe`) in order to make Windows forget the bad file association choice:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.exe\\UserChoice
```

as you can see in the [link](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/165/1/Restore-the-exe-file-association-in-Windows-Vista-after-incorrectly-associating-it-with-another-application.html) of [loviji](https://superuser.com/users/38036/loviji)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/q/144935/129520).

In general, you delete the key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.xyz\UserChoice
```

where you replace `.xyz` with either `.exe`, `.bat`, `.cmd`, `.com`, `.lnk`, or anything else you need.