# All files trying to start in Notepad

Tags: windows-7, file-association, notepad, regedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Window7 troubleshooting .exe is not opening](https://superuser.com/questions/144935/window7-troubleshooting-exe-is-not-opening)

This question has been asked, but the solutions given were worthless to me because ALL files are trying to open in Notepad. I mistakenly associated all `exe` files with Notepad and everything is trying to open within Notepad now. That **includes** `regedit`, so suggesting I use `regedit` to doctor files does not work (cmd window will not open from <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - Run).

It also includes any program I download to fix the issue. I also can not right click and choose Open With because that is not a given option when right clicking on a majority of files, at least none of the `exe` files I want to start. Yes, I tried it on the program files, not the shortcut. I also can not use System Restore because it, too, tries to open in Notepad. I've been banging my head uselessly on this for hours. Could someone help me out?

Comment: As a side note: If you can't open CMD normally, press Ctrl+Shift+Escape, then select **File**, press and hold the Ctrl key, and click New Task. It will bring up a CMD window, run as Admin

Comment: Can you rename an `.exe` file as a `.com`?  It should still execute but it won't have the same association.

Answer (score 1):

One thing encourages us. Only the executables are associated with notepad. But, the extensions that are opened by those exe's are still associated with the same exe's (like .doc --> still opens with Word). So, our keen weapon is "`.reg` file" which is still opened and merged by `regedit`.

**Note:** I have no experience with Windows-7 because I'm still digging with XP. But, this method maybe of help. Now, [Let the siege begin..!](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-exe-file-asso-windows-7-vista-incorrectly-associated/)

This question (already asked here) could be of help: [How do you associate the .exe file extension with a program in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/354771/how-do-you-associate-the-exe-file-extension-with-a-program-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Use this FixIt to restore the ability to run Exe files:

**[Can't open .EXE files in Windows 7 or Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688326)**

Comment: and changed assignations and that cause exe no longer work. He also posted this.The FixIt comes as MSI so that it can run and restore the broken association.